# Appending two keypaths in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to append two KeyPaths in Swift (4), but the compiler either won't let me, or the result is 'nil' despite being a valid keypath.

Classes:

```
import Foundation

@objcMembers
class Foo: NSObject
{
    @objc public dynamic var items = [1, 2, 3]
}

@objcMembers
class Bar: NSObject
{
    @objc public dynamic var source: NSObject?
}
```

Example 1:

```
let keyPath1 = \Bar.source
let keyPath2 = \Foo.items
keyPath1.appending(path: keyPath2) // error: cannot convert value of type 'ReferenceWritableKeyPath<Foo, [Int]>' to expected argument type 'WritableKeyPath<_, _>' keyPath1.appending(path: keyPath2)
```

Example 2:

```
let keyPath1: WritableKeyPath<Bar, NSObject?> = \Bar.source
let keyPath2: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<Foo, [Int]> = \Foo.items
keyPath1.appending(path: keyPath2) // error: ambiguous reference to member 'appending(path:)'
```

Example 3:

```
let keyPath1: AnyKeyPath = \Bar.source
let keyPath2: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<Foo, [Int]> = \Foo.items
keyPath1.appending(path: keyPath2) // returns nil
```

The classes here are intentionally using a optional member of type `NSObject`. The resulting keyPath should be `source.items` which on a instance of `Foo` is a valid keyPath.

What's the correct combination of the new Swift 4 keyPath types to make this work?

Comment: You have to use correct types in the first place. `source` should be declared as `Foo`, not as `NSObject`. You app would crash if you used this and `source` wouldn't be a `Foo` instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all to use Swift 4 keypaths the objects are **not** required to inherit from `NSObject`(not even to be a class) and have KVC compliant properties.

Second of all `NSObject` is similar to `AnyObject` but Swift 4 key paths need concrete static types.

Finally the property `source` is optional so you have to unwrap the key path to be valid.

---

To be able to concatenate key paths the last component of the first key path must be of the same type as the first component of the second key path

This is the *.appending Rule* from [WWDC 2017 - Session 212: What's new in Foundation](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/212/)

[image]

You can append key paths this way

```
class Foo {
    var items = [1, 2, 3]
}


class Bar {
    var source: Foo?
}

let bar = Bar()
bar.source = Foo()

let keyPath1 = \Bar.source!
let keyPath2 = \Foo.items
let keyPath = keyPath1.appending(path: keyPath2)

let items = bar[keyPath:keyPath]
print(items)
```